# Lifecycle issue using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**My user State**

`const [user, setUser] = useState({});`

**Fetch Function**

```
    async function checkIfUserIsEnabled() {
        let URL = `http://localhost:8080/users/finduserbytoken?id=`;
        const res = await fetch(URL);
        res.json()
           .then(res => setUser(res))
           .catch(err => setErrors(err));
      }
```

**useEffect**(calling the fetch method, `checkIfUserIsEnabled`)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL);
        checkIfUserIsEnabled();
        return () => {
            /* */
        };
    }, []);
```

**Return**

```
    return (
        <div className="emailVerificationWrapper">
        {user.enabled ? <h1>Result is true!</h1> : <h1>Result is false</h1>}
        </div>
    )
```

**My Issue:** is that the return method is called before the state causing the `user.enabled` to always be false, even though the `setUser`, which is called in the useEffect updated the state of `user.enabled` to true.

**How can i make the state update before getting to the render?**

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to design the component in a way that handles itself before the data is returned? You have no control over how long a `fetch` will take anyway--design things appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, you are calling async functions which will not be executed on the same order on the `useEffect`, so I propose you clean the functions a bit like:

```js
const checkIfUserIsEnabled = (user) => {
  if (user)
    setUser({ enabled: true, ...user })
}
const getUser = () => {
  let URL = `http://localhost:8080/users/finduserbytoken?id=`;
  const res = await fetch(URL);
  const user = res.json()
  checkIfUserIsEnabled(user)
}


useEffect(() => {
  verifyEmail(getTokenIdFromURL)
    .then(verified => {
      getUser()
    })
}, []);


  return (
        <div className="emailVerificationWrapper">
           <h1>{` Result is ${user.enabled}`}</h1>
           <br/>
           <div>Current User State:</div>
           <pre>{JSON.stringify(usre)}</pre>
        </div>
    )
```

> now it's easier for you to debug and cleaner to read